# Postgres hash join batches explosion

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

We are having some struggle identifying why Postgres is using too much batches to resolve a join.

Here it is the output of explain analyze of a problematic execution:
https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/xNJ#plan

```sql
 Limit  (cost=20880.87..20882.91 rows=48 width=205) (actual time=10722.953..10723.358 rows=48 loops=1)
   ->  Unique  (cost=20880.87..21718.12 rows=19700 width=205) (actual time=10722.951..10723.356 rows=48 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=20880.87..20930.12 rows=19700 width=205) (actual time=10722.950..10722.990 rows=312 loops=1)
               Sort Key: titlemetadata_titlemetadata.creation_date DESC, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.id, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.title_type, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.original_title, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.alternative_ids, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.metadata,
titlemetadata_titlemetadata.is_adult, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.is_kids, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.last_modified, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.year, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.runtime, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.rating, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.video_provider, tit
lemetadata_titlemetadata.series_id_id, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.season_number, titlemetadata_titlemetadata.episode_number
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 872kB
               ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=13378.20..19475.68 rows=19700 width=205) (actual time=1926.352..10709.970 rows=2909 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (t4.titlemetadata_id = t3.id)
                     Filter: ((hashed SubPlan 1) OR (hashed SubPlan 2))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 63248
                     ->  Seq Scan on video_provider_offer t4  (cost=0.00..5454.90 rows=66290 width=16) (actual time=0.024..57.893 rows=66390 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=11314.39..11314.39 rows=22996 width=221) (actual time=489.530..489.530 rows=60096 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 65536 (originally 32768)  Batches: 32768 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 11656kB
                           ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=5380.95..11314.39 rows=22996 width=221) (actual time=130.024..225.271 rows=60096 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: (video_provider_offer.titlemetadata_id = titlemetadata_titlemetadata.id)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on video_provider_offer  (cost=0.00..5454.90 rows=66290 width=16) (actual time=0.011..32.950 rows=66390 loops=1)
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=5129.28..5129.28 rows=20133 width=213) (actual time=129.897..129.897 rows=55793 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 65536 (originally 32768)  Batches: 2 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 7877kB
                                       ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1.72..5129.28 rows=20133 width=213) (actual time=0.041..93.057 rows=55793 loops=1)
                                             Merge Cond: (titlemetadata_titlemetadata.id = t3.series_id_id)
                                             ->  Index Scan using titlemetadata_titlemetadata_pkey on titlemetadata_titlemetadata  (cost=1.30..4130.22 rows=20133 width=205) (actual time=0.028..62.949 rows=43921 loops=1)
                                                   Filter: ((NOT is_adult) AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 3)) AND (((title_type)::text = 'MOV'::text) OR ((title_type)::text = 'TVS'::text) OR ((title_type)::text = 'TVP'::text) OR ((title_type)::text = 'EVT'::text)))
                                                   Rows Removed by Filter: 14121
                                                   SubPlan 3
                                                     ->  Seq Scan on cable_operator_cableoperatorexcludedtitle u0_2  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                           Filter: (cable_operator_id = 54)
                                             ->  Index Scan using titlemetadata_titlemetadata_series_id_id_73453db4_uniq on titlemetadata_titlemetadata t3  (cost=0.41..3901.36 rows=58037 width=16) (actual time=0.011..9.375 rows=12887 loops=1)
                     SubPlan 1
                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=44.62..885.73 rows=981 width=8) (actual time=0.486..36.806 rows=5757 loops=1)
                             Hash Cond: (w2.device_id = w3.id)
                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=43.49..866.20 rows=2289 width=16) (actual time=0.441..33.096 rows=20180 loops=1)
                                   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=43.06..414.98 rows=521 width=8) (actual time=0.426..9.952 rows=2909 loops=1)
                                         Join Filter: (w1.id = w0.video_provider_id)
                                         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=42.65..54.77 rows=13 width=24) (actual time=0.399..0.532 rows=15 loops=1)
                                               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=42.50..42.95 rows=45 width=16) (actual time=0.390..0.403 rows=45 loops=1)
                                                     Group Key: v0.id
                                                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=13.34..42.39 rows=45 width=16) (actual time=0.095..0.364 rows=45 loops=1)
                                                           ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=13.19..32.72 rows=45 width=8) (actual time=0.084..0.229 rows=45 loops=1)
                                                                 Hash Cond: (v1.id = u0.id)
                                                                 ->  Seq Scan on cable_operator_cableoperatorprovider v1  (cost=0.00..17.36 rows=636 width=16) (actual time=0.010..0.077 rows=636 loops=1)
                                                                 ->  Hash  (cost=12.63..12.63 rows=45 width=8) (actual time=0.046..0.046 rows=45 loops=1)
                                                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                                                                       ->  Index Scan using cable_operator_cableoperatorprovider_4d6e54b3 on cable_operator_cableoperatorprovider u0  (cost=0.28..12.63 rows=45 width=8) (actual time=0.016..0.035 rows=45 loops=1)
                                                                             Index Cond: (cable_operator_id = 54)
                                                           ->  Index Only Scan using video_provider_videoprovider_pkey on video_provider_videoprovider v0  (cost=0.15..0.20 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=45)
                                                                 Index Cond: (id = v1.provider_id)
                                                                 Heap Fetches: 45
                                               ->  Index Scan using video_provider_videoprovider_pkey on video_provider_videoprovider w1  (cost=0.15..0.25 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=45)
                                                     Index Cond: (id = v0.id)
                                                     Filter: ((video_provider_type)::text = 'VOD'::text)
                                                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                         ->  Index Scan using video_provider_offer_da942d2e on video_provider_offer w0  (cost=0.42..27.22 rows=39 width=16) (actual time=0.026..0.585 rows=194 loops=15)
                                               Index Cond: (video_provider_id = v0.id)
                                               Filter: (((end_date > '2021-09-02 19:23:00-03'::timestamp with time zone) OR (end_date IS NULL)) AND (access_criteria && '{vtv_mas,TBX_LOGIN,urn:spkg:tve:fox-premium,urn:tve:mcp,AMCHD,AMC_CONSORCIO,ANIMAL_PLANET,ASUNTOS_PUBLI
COS,ASUNTOS_PUBLICOS_CONSORCIO,CINECANALLIVE,CINECANAL_CONSORCIO,DISCOVERY,DISCOVERY_KIDS_CONSORCIO,DISCOVERY_KIDS_OD,DISNEY,DISNEY_CH_CONSORCIO,DISNEY_XD,DISNEY_XD_CONSORCIO,EL_CANAL_HD,EL_CANAL_HD_CONSORCIO,EL_GOURMET_CONSORCIO,ESPN,ESPN2_HD_CONSORCIO,ESPN3_HD_CONSORCIO
,ESPNMAS_HD_CONSORCIO,ESPN_BASIC,ESPN_HD_CONSORCIO,ESPN_PLAY,EUROPALIVE,EUROPA_EUROPA,EUROPA_EUROPA_CONSORCIO,FILMANDARTS_DISPOSITIVOS,FILMS_ARTS,FILM_AND_ARTS_CONSORCIO,FOXLIFE,FOX_LIFE_CONSORCIO,FOX_SPORTS_1_DISPOSITIVOS,FOX_SPORTS_2_DISPOSITIVOS,FOX_SPORTS_2_HD_CONSORC
IO,FOX_SPORTS_3_DISPOSITIVOS,FOX_SPORTS_3_HD_CONSORCIO,FOX_SPORTS_HD_CONSORCIO,FRANCE24_DISPOSITIVOS,FRANCE_24_CONSORCIO,GOURMET,GOURMET_DISPOSITIVOS,HOME_HEALTH,INVESTIGATION_DISCOVERY,MAS_CHIC,NATGEOKIDS_DISPOSITIVOS,NATGEO_CONSORCIO,NATGEO_DISPOSITIVOS,NATGEO_KIDS_CONS
ORCIO,PASIONES,PASIONES_CONSORCIO,SVOD_TYC_BASIC,TBX_LOGIN,TCC_2_CONSORCIO,TCC_2_HD,TLC,TVE,TVE_CONSORCIO,TYC_SPORTS_CONSORCIO,VTV_LIVE,clarosports,discoverykids,espnplay_south_alt,urn:spkg:tve:fox-basic,urn:tve:babytv,urn:tve:cinecanal,urn:tve:discoverykids,urn:tve:foxli
fe,urn:tve:fp,urn:tve:fx,urn:tve:natgeo,urn:tve:natgeokids,urn:tve:natgeowild,urn:tve:thefilmzone}'::character varying(50)[]) AND ((((content_type)::text = 'VOD'::text) AND ((start_date < '2021-09-02 19:23:00-03'::timestamp with time zone) OR (start_date IS NULL))) OR ((c
ontent_type)::text = 'LIV'::text)))
                                               Rows Removed by Filter: 5
                                   ->  Index Only Scan using video_provider_offer_devices_offer_id_device_id_key on video_provider_offer_devices w2  (cost=0.42..0.81 rows=6 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.007 rows=7 loops=2909)
                                         Index Cond: (offer_id = w0.id)
                                         Heap Fetches: 17828
                             ->  Hash  (cost=1.10..1.10 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=2 loops=1)
                                   Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                   ->  Seq Scan on platform_device_device w3  (cost=0.00..1.10 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.024..0.027 rows=2 loops=1)
                                         Filter: ((device_code)::text = ANY ('{ANDROID,ott_dual_tcc,ott_k2_tcc}'::text[]))
                                         Rows Removed by Filter: 5
                     SubPlan 2
                       ->  Hash Join  (cost=44.62..885.73 rows=981 width=8) (actual time=0.410..33.580 rows=5757 loops=1)
                             Hash Cond: (w2_1.device_id = w3_1.id)
                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=43.49..866.20 rows=2289 width=16) (actual time=0.375..29.886 rows=20180 loops=1)
                                   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=43.06..414.98 rows=521 width=8) (actual time=0.366..9.134 rows=2909 loops=1)
                                         Join Filter: (w1_1.id = w0_1.video_provider_id)
                                         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=42.65..54.77 rows=13 width=24) (actual time=0.343..0.476 rows=15 loops=1)
                                               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=42.50..42.95 rows=45 width=16) (actual time=0.333..0.347 rows=45 loops=1)
                                                     Group Key: v0_1.id
                                                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=13.34..42.39 rows=45 width=16) (actual time=0.083..0.311 rows=45 loops=1)
                                                           ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=13.19..32.72 rows=45 width=8) (actual time=0.076..0.202 rows=45 loops=1)
                                                                 Hash Cond: (v1_1.id = u0_1.id)
                                                                 ->  Seq Scan on cable_operator_cableoperatorprovider v1_1  (cost=0.00..17.36 rows=636 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.057 rows=636 loops=1)
                                                                 ->  Hash  (cost=12.63..12.63 rows=45 width=8) (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=45 loops=1)
                                                                       Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
                                                                       ->  Index Scan using cable_operator_cableoperatorprovider_4d6e54b3 on cable_operator_cableoperatorprovider u0_1  (cost=0.28..12.63 rows=45 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.020 rows=45 loops=1)
                                                                             Index Cond: (cable_operator_id = 54)
                                                           ->  Index Only Scan using video_provider_videoprovider_pkey on video_provider_videoprovider v0_1  (cost=0.15..0.20 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=45)
                                                                 Index Cond: (id = v1_1.provider_id)
                                                                 Heap Fetches: 45
                                               ->  Index Scan using video_provider_videoprovider_pkey on video_provider_videoprovider w1_1  (cost=0.15..0.25 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=45)
                                                     Index Cond: (id = v0_1.id)
                                                     Filter: ((video_provider_type)::text = 'VOD'::text)
                                                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                                         ->  Index Scan using video_provider_offer_da942d2e on video_provider_offer w0_1  (cost=0.42..27.22 rows=39 width=16) (actual time=0.022..0.536 rows=194 loops=15)
                                               Index Cond: (video_provider_id = v0_1.id)
                                               Filter: (((end_date > '2021-09-02 19:23:00-03'::timestamp with time zone) OR (end_date IS NULL)) AND (access_criteria && '{vtv_mas,TBX_LOGIN,urn:spkg:tve:fox-premium,urn:tve:mcp,AMCHD,AMC_CONSORCIO,ANIMAL_PLANET,ASUNTOS_PUBLI
COS,ASUNTOS_PUBLICOS_CONSORCIO,CINECANALLIVE,CINECANAL_CONSORCIO,DISCOVERY,DISCOVERY_KIDS_CONSORCIO,DISCOVERY_KIDS_OD,DISNEY,DISNEY_CH_CONSORCIO,DISNEY_XD,DISNEY_XD_CONSORCIO,EL_CANAL_HD,EL_CANAL_HD_CONSORCIO,EL_GOURMET_CONSORCIO,ESPN,ESPN2_HD_CONSORCIO,ESPN3_HD_CONSORCIO
,ESPNMAS_HD_CONSORCIO,ESPN_BASIC,ESPN_HD_CONSORCIO,ESPN_PLAY,EUROPALIVE,EUROPA_EUROPA,EUROPA_EUROPA_CONSORCIO,FILMANDARTS_DISPOSITIVOS,FILMS_ARTS,FILM_AND_ARTS_CONSORCIO,FOXLIFE,FOX_LIFE_CONSORCIO,FOX_SPORTS_1_DISPOSITIVOS,FOX_SPORTS_2_DISPOSITIVOS,FOX_SPORTS_2_HD_CONSORC
IO,FOX_SPORTS_3_DISPOSITIVOS,FOX_SPORTS_3_HD_CONSORCIO,FOX_SPORTS_HD_CONSORCIO,FRANCE24_DISPOSITIVOS,FRANCE_24_CONSORCIO,GOURMET,GOURMET_DISPOSITIVOS,HOME_HEALTH,INVESTIGATION_DISCOVERY,MAS_CHIC,NATGEOKIDS_DISPOSITIVOS,NATGEO_CONSORCIO,NATGEO_DISPOSITIVOS,NATGEO_KIDS_CONS
ORCIO,PASIONES,PASIONES_CONSORCIO,SVOD_TYC_BASIC,TBX_LOGIN,TCC_2_CONSORCIO,TCC_2_HD,TLC,TVE,TVE_CONSORCIO,TYC_SPORTS_CONSORCIO,VTV_LIVE,clarosports,discoverykids,espnplay_south_alt,urn:spkg:tve:fox-basic,urn:tve:babytv,urn:tve:cinecanal,urn:tve:discoverykids,urn:tve:foxli
fe,urn:tve:fp,urn:tve:fx,urn:tve:natgeo,urn:tve:natgeokids,urn:tve:natgeowild,urn:tve:thefilmzone}'::character varying(50)[]) AND ((((content_type)::text = 'VOD'::text) AND ((start_date < '2021-09-02 19:23:00-03'::timestamp with time zone) OR (start_date IS NULL))) OR ((c
ontent_type)::text = 'LIV'::text)))
                                               Rows Removed by Filter: 5
                                   ->  Index Only Scan using video_provider_offer_devices_offer_id_device_id_key on video_provider_offer_devices w2_1  (cost=0.42..0.81 rows=6 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.006 rows=7 loops=2909)
                                         Index Cond: (offer_id = w0_1.id)
                                         Heap Fetches: 17828
                             ->  Hash  (cost=1.10..1.10 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=2 loops=1)
                                   Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                   ->  Seq Scan on platform_device_device w3_1  (cost=0.00..1.10 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=2 loops=1)
                                         Filter: ((device_code)::text = ANY ('{ANDROID,ott_dual_tcc,ott_k2_tcc}'::text[]))
                                         Rows Removed by Filter: 5
 Planning time: 8.255 ms
 Execution time: 10723.830 ms
(100 rows)
```

The weird part is that the same query, sometimes just uses a single batch. Here is an example: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/zTv#plan

Here is the work_mem being used:

```
show work_mem;
 work_mem
----------
 8388kB
(1 row)
```

I'm not interested in changing the query to be more performant, but in understanding why is the different behavior.

I've found this thread apparently related with this, but I don't quite understand what are they talking about: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CA%2BhUKGKWWmf%3DWELLG%3DaUGbcugRaSQbtm0tKYiBut-B2rVKX63g%40mail.gmail.com

Can anyone tell me why is this different behavior? The underlying data is the same in both cases.

Comment: `Buckets: 65536 (originally 32768)  Batches: 32768 (originally 1)` looks like a software bug, since these are powers of two. If you can come up with a reproducer, please report it to the project. Is this normal PostgreSQL?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes, is normal PostgreSQL. This is the exact version: PostgreSQL 9.6.22 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (Debian 9.6.22-1.pgdg100+1), compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit. I'll try to come up with a reproducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We where able to solve the problem just by doing `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE;`.
After that, everything started to work as expected (https://explain.depesz.com/s/eoqH#html)

Side note: we where not aware that we should do this on daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

If the hash is done in memory, there will only be a single batch.

A difference with the original hash batch numbers is due to Postgres choosing to increase the number of batches in order to reduce memory consumption.

You might find this EXPLAIN glossary useful (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors), here is [the page on Hash Batches](https://www.pgmustard.com/docs/explain/hash-batches) which also links to the PostgreSQL source code (it's very nicely documented in plain English).

While not a perfect heuristic, you can see that the memory required for the operations with multiple batches are around or above your `work_mem` setting. They can be lower than it, due to operations on disk generally requiring less memory overall.

I'm not 100% sure why in your exact case one was chosen over the other, but it does look like there are some very slight row estimate differences, which might be a good place to start.

As of PostgreSQL 13 there is also now a [`hash_mem_multiplier`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-HASH-MEM-MULTIPLIER) setting that can be used to give more memory to hashes without doing so for other operations (like sorts).